# Ruby on Rails 3 Tiered Link Program

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> My app is a web forum. Root page is a list of user-submitted
>   categories. I click one and it links to a list of user-submitted posts
>   about that category. I click a post and it links to a list of comments
>   about that post. Those are the 3 tiers.

**CATEGORIES INDEX** *This is a list of clickable categories*

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<%= link_to category.title, category %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

**CATEGORIES SHOW** *I clicked a category, now I'm here looking at a list of posts*

```
<%= render :partial => @category.posts %>
<% end %>
```

**_POSTS** *The posts are rendered from this here partial*

```
<%= div_for(post) do %>
<%= link_to post.body, Post  %>
```

[image]

Clicking that post link takes me to **POSTS INDEX**.

> I'm not sure if this is a desirable flow of a Rails app. It seems odd
>   to go from Categories, to Posts, to Comments using Categories_Index,
>   Categories_Show, and Posts_Index, respectively. I don't know how to display or submit comments from this POSTS INDEX. @comments.each do |comments| provides an error and so does the render: partial method. I can not use the same methods for Comments that I used for Categories and Posts.

**MODELS** *Models are complete with has_many, belongs_to, etc.*

**CATEGORIES CONTROLLER**
    def index
    @categories = Category.all
    end
    def create
    @category = current_user.categories.build(categories_params)
    end

**POSTS CONTROLLER**
     def create
     @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
     @post = @category.posts.new(post_params)

**COMMENTS CONTROLLER**
     def index
     @subcomments = Subcomment.all
     end
     def create
     @subcomment = current_user.subcomments.build(subcomment_params)
     end

**ROUTES**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :comments

resources :posts
devise_for :users
resources :categories do

resources :posts do
end
resources :comments
end
root "categories#index"
```

***I successfully added posts to categories. How can I add comments to posts? Is my approach correct?***

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you have the following Model Relationships:

**Model Category**

```
has_many :posts
```

**Model Post**

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :category
```

**Model Comment**

```
belongs_to :post
```

You are asking "**How can I add comments to posts?**"

In the page where you render all **POSTS** data,
you should **USE** posts **ID** as you main parameter.

So, meaning you should have **post_id** column/field inside ***Comments Table***.

After saving the comments data, usually like [title, message, date ....].

In your **Post Controller**, you can get comments like:

```
// multiple Posts data
@posts = Post.all
@post.each do |post|
 post.comments
 ...
end

//single Post

@post = Post.first // or Post.find(:id => params[:post_id])
@post.comments
```

If you are sending data using form, just put some **hidden text field**,

setting the **name & value**:

```
name="post_id" 
// or something like:
name="comment[:post_id]"     
//depends on how you constract the form.
```

Then set the value:

```
value="<%= params[:post_id ]%>"
```

Finnally, you can get the value like getting the other **comments_field names.**

*Usually* you should have this in in **config/routes.rb**,

```
resources :commets
```

Then your **FORM path** is like:

```
<%= form_for @comment, :url => @comments_path %>
```

Your **Comments Controller** should have like:

```
def index
  ...
end

def show
  ...
end

def edit
  ...
end


def new
  @comment = Comment.new
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.create(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
    ....
    redirect_to comments_path
  else
    .....
  end
end

# For params permit in Rails 4 ^
def comment_params
   params.require(:comment).permit!
end
```

Comment: I do have a post_id associated with each comment. I'm still not sure though how to display comments.

Comment: do you have separate page for adding category, adding post & adding comment?

Comment: No, it's just tacked on to the bottom. See the second image for an example. If there was a comment there, it would appear before the comment box.

Comment: alrigth that is much easy to setup. just post the comments data with post_id

Comment: The method I used to submit the post data with category_id is not working to submit comment data with post_id.  I'm not sure if the problem is with my routes, or what

Comment: Please check updated code for routing and controller codes.